# customize SOAP response in asmx webmethod - put an extra xml element before the method response

Tags: iis, soap, asmx

I'm modifing an old asmx webservice (XSD schema) and I'm a newbie in that :)

How Can I insert an xml element before the webmethod response?

Now:

```
xmlns="http://.... "><response> <?XML version> <field1>blah blah</field1>etc... </response>
```

Desired:

```
xmlns="http://.... "><field0>blah blah</field0><response> <?XML version...> <field1>blah blah</field1>etc... </response>
```

Thanks

Comment: You can write an httpmodule and deploy it to IIS. So that you can inject anything to response body before client receiving it.https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/nov/13/capturing-and-transforming-aspnet-output-with-responsefilter

Comment: Thanks, but I can't figure out how to implement your solution in my case... Can you help me more in detail, please?    Or there is another simplest way to do this?
Now I have implemented a simple asmx using [webmethod] with XSD schema... Using [return: System.XML.Serialization.XMLElement I have changed the name of the returned element response... There is a similar way to add an element just before that?

Comment: What about give up operating xml element directly then read response string and just insert the <field0>blah blah</field0> into that string？

Comment: Do you mean insert the desired piece of xml in the result output of my webmethod (before send it)? And how can I do that, please? Can you show me some demo code?

Comment: Can anyone help me anymore, please? With some tutorial code or some useful link? Thanks

Comment: You can use regex expression to index the location and insert the string.

Comment: Thank you very much! Ill' try your suggestions.